# Works with CURL how to format for Postman/REST client

Tags: rest, post, curl, postman

I'm sure this is a dumb question but I haven't been able to see the light.

If I have a curl command ...

```
curl -v  -F "dataType=dws" -F "format=csv" -F "compression=gzip" -F "sha256sum=17685b28be3af7b71bcab78c0393d548d7cd563f3fd5d955309c9512a4ad28ad" -F "file=@/Users/xxx/sql/file.gz" http://localhost:8080/p20/fileUpload
```

that works perfectly, how do I do the same thing via Postman(or any REST client) ?

Thanks in advance for enlightening me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t-F means Formdata. Normally used for the data from the form fields of a HTML page, which are typically submitted by an POST Request to the server. Curl builds a data string and send it in the body of the HTTP request.
An equivalent to your curl statement is:

```
curl -v -X POST -d "dataType=dws&format=csv&compression=gzip&sha256sum=17685b28be3af7b71bcab78c0393d548d7cd563f3fd5d955309c9512a4ad28ad&file=@/Users/xxx/sql/file.gz" http://localhost:8080/p20/fileUpload
```

curl treats the file=@... as a special command. It reads the file and appends the content to the body. It also set the mime type to `multipart/formdata`.

Thats all you must do in postman or equivalent. Enter the string after -d in the body/content field. Set the method to POST. Enter the URL.

-v increases the verbosity level. I don't know how to make postman more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent [blog post](http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/06/13/debugging-postman-requests/) on Postman.com that gives detailed step by step instructions to turn on verbose mode in postman application. This allows you to observe raw HTTP requests and also do much more debugging.